# managing several cloud services at once

Tags: php, api, dropbox, box-api

I am working on implementing several cloud services in one program. I have created APIs with Dropbox and Box and try to access them simultaneous. In spite of logging into both the services I am able to get details of only one account. Also I am trying to display list of services I am logged in but I am getting only one service name even at that time. I am using PHP for development.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Are you using the provided SDKs or interacting with the API's through other means? When you say you log into both services, does that mean that you have received both the access token and refresh token for both services?

Comment: yes I receive access token for both Services. I don't get refresh token. Please tell me what information you require so that I can explain it in detail

Comment: Perhaps providing some code snippets of how you're formatting the requests, and what endpoints you're hitting would be helpful

Comment: I have two different programs that manages API client library and allow log in to two services. I then pass the name of logged in cloud service using session variable. That session variable value is then added to global variable which then is used to display all logged in services. Following is the code snippet for the same:    <br />$cloud_service = $_SESSION['cloud'];<br/>
echo $cloud_service;<br/>
$n=0;<br/>

if($cloud_service == 'dropbox') 
{
$logged_cs[0] = $cloud_service;
$n++;